# Не все со всех страниц возвращается html. Выводит 301 ошибку Moved

Tags: c++, ubuntu, websocket

Я хочу сделать подобие функции wget в линуксе. 
Проблема в том, что нормальный html ответ я получаю только для www.google.com
вот что например возвращается для www.mail.ru

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 05:56:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://mail.ru/
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 184
Connection: close
Age: 0

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Ниже код запроса, я думаю проблема в этом сообщении:

```
<br>GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: fetch.c\r\n\r\n
```

Его я отправляю в функции `read()`

Вот так я создаю сокет:

```
int socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    puts("could not create socket");

}

char* ip = new char;
getHost_byName(hostname, ip);
int success = read(ip, socket_desc, hostname);
if (success != 0)
{
    puts("Error");
}

close(socket_desc);
```

В этой функции посылаю сообщение и получаю ответ:

```
int read(char* address, int socket_desc, char* hostname)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );
    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");
    puts(hostname);

    char* message;
    const char * format = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: fetch.c\r\n\r\n";
    int status = asprintf(& message, format, hostname);
    if (status == -1)
    {
        printf("asprintf doesn't work");
        return 1;
    }
    //puts(message);
    if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("send failed");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("data send");

    //-recv - calls are used to receive messages from a socket
    int size_recv , total_size= 0, BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
    char chunk[BLOCK_SIZE];

    ofstream fout(getFileName(hostname));
    //loop
    while(1)
    {
        memset(chunk ,0 , BLOCK_SIZE);  //clear the variable
        if((size_recv = recv(socket_desc , chunk , BLOCK_SIZE, 0) ) < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            fout << chunk;
            printf("%s" , chunk);
        }
    }

    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код ни при чем - это перенаправление, нормальный ответ 301, который вы должны отработать в программе и запросить страницу по новому, указанному в ответе адресу (кстати, с отслеживанием, где вы уже были - чтоб не попасть в замкнутый цикл, если кто неверно сервер настроит :)). Так сказать, читайте документацию по протоколу http...

Comment: ясненько, спасибо за совет, пойду поищу как это делается и с чем его едят

Comment: вот такой вопрос:
gethostbyname эта фунция если подать ей http:// + mail.ru/ то что находится в ответе в поле location возвращает ответ Unknown host. Почему такое может быть?
n

Comment: Потому что передавать ей нужно только имя, а не URL - `mail.ru`.

Comment: теперь я получаю 500 Internal server error